# permanently enable a button and change its image src with jQuery and LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a `disabled` button that I want to enable by clicking another button and keep it permanently enabled. That button has an image and at the same time as the button gets enabled the image `src` should change. This is my code:

```
<!--This is the button that enables the img_tema2 button-->
<a id="a_tema1" href="principal.html" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</a>

<!--This is the img_tema2 button-->
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <button class="tsbutton" onclick="window.location='tema_2.html';" id="img_tema2">
        Tema 2
        <img id="gif_tema2" class="img-circle2" src="../assets/img/segundo_tema_gris.gif" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
    </button>
</div>
```

```js
$("#img_tema2").prop("disabled", true);

$(function () {
    var showLittleHeader = localStorage.getItem('#img_tema2');

    if (showLittleHeader) {
        $("#img_tema2").prop("disabled", false);
    }

    $('#a_tema1').on('click', function () {
        localStorage.setItem('#img_tema2', 1);
        $("#img_tema2").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Sorry, I totally forgot to explain a lot of things.

The `a_tema1` its on a different HTML.
When I open my html the button `img_tema2` is not disabled, and as I said up, I need it to be first disabled and when I click the `a_tema1`, it gets enabled.
Adding the line `$("#img_tema2 img").attr("src", '');` that was recommended, it doesn´t do anything neither.
 What could I be doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad english an thanks for all the help you can give me

Comment: the image src should change to what?  What about your code isn't working now?

Comment: Why are you assigning a `href` on that `<a` used as a button? You need to disable the default click action using `e.preventDefault()` to make anything work.`$('#a_tema1').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); //other code`

Comment: $("#img_tema2").prop("disabled", false); after this add $("#img_tema2 img").attr("src", 'new-img-src'); if you want to change image when button is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but this is my interpretation:

https://jsfiddle.net/tzf8c50k/

HTML:

```
<!--This is the button that enables the img_tema2 button-->
<div id="a_tema1" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</div>
<br/><br/>
<!--This is the img_tema2 button-->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <button class="btn" onclick="window.location='tema_2.html';" id="img_tema2">
    Tema 2
    <img id="gif_tema2" class="img-circle2" src="https://i.imgur.com/fBE8b1k.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
  </button>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>Icons made by <a href="http://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="http://www.flaticon.com" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0"
  target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></p>
```

JS:

```
$("#img_tema2").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$(function() {
    var showLittleHeader = localStorage.getItem('#img_tema2');
    if (showLittleHeader) {
      $("#img_tema2").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#gif_tema2").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/fNerL36.png");
    }

  $('#a_tema1').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("#img_tema2", 1);
    $("#gif_tema2").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/fNerL36.png");
    $("#img_tema2").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed, thanks a lot man, you really saved my life